# CodeIgniter 2.2.0 on upgraded server good save for HTTPS/SSL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

We upgraded our server for a 10 year old website recently and the lowest allowable PHP version the host would install was 7.4.  Understandable.

When we moved the old CodeIgniter 2.2.0 site over to the new machine, we were quite surprised with the amount of stuff that was still working.  After squashing some environmental and PHP version bugs, we did a QA.  Everything is peachy save for the home or "defualt_controller" route stuff.

If I summon any asset or anything routed through https://example.com/***admin/*** by HTTPS, I get 200 with no issues.  If I clone static HTML into PHP files and drop them in to directories, they'll serve securely.

I've tooled around with index.php and even core/CodeIgniter.php and the returns to those requests serve 200 OK under HTTPS.

If I request any dynamically generated document on the publicly visible part of the site, it's constantly ***HTTPS*** 302 Found -> ***HTTP*** 200 OK

If I do very aggressive .htacccess stuff, the server fights back and the browser goes: "Too many redirects"

Has anyone dealt with this?  I am assuming something in the core is silently erroring out?

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case there was a conditional statement in a library that required $_SERVER['HTTPS'] to return TRUE.  This server was returning NULL which went to the next condition which summoned force_non_ssl();

Thanks!